# Bug with firebug window

Tags: jquery, firebug

I have a site and there are many divs in it, for header, middle, main and footer.

I have an jquery slideshow on middle, and 2 in main part but there is an empty space between middle and main part, and also under the footer part. I tried to fix the problem about the part under the footer.

My problem is that when i want to fix the part between middle and main and open the firebug, it will reduce the empty part slowly-like jquery slide up or down and i can see it is solved!! when i close the firebug again, the problem goes back!

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: any screenshots or source code or name of jQuery you have used?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried launching Firebug in 'detached' mode (this opens it in a separate window) - this shouldn't affect the layout of the current page.

Comment: thanks so much,i hope i can fix it, i dont know where is the problem from anyway :(